WPF Combobox Binding not updating
I have a WPF app with two comboboxes that represent production/mfg engineers assigned to a job, where CurrentEngNotice is the relevant job:
<TextBlock Text="Product Engineer:" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyleTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ProductionEngineers}" 
      DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
      SelectedValuePath="UserID"
      SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.ProductEng.UserID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Manufacturing Engineer:" Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyleTextBlock}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding ManufacturingEngineers}" 
     DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
     SelectedValuePath="UserID"
     SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.MfgEng.UserID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

The bindings for these comboboxes sort of works, because it is showing the correct value for what is populated in the database. However, when I change this field from the app the setter for the field does not run and the database is therefore not updated. These are the bound properties:
    public Engineer ProductEng
    {
        get { return _productEngineer; }
        set 
        {
            if (_productEngineer != value)
            {
                _productEngineer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                UpdateDatabase("PRODUCT_ENG", value.UserID);
            }

        }
    }

    public Engineer MfgEng
    {
        get { return _mfgEngineer; }
        set
        {
            if (_mfgEngineer != value)
            {
                _mfgEngineer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                UpdateDatabase("MFG_ENG", value.UserID);
            }

        }
    }

By debugging I've confirmed that the problem is not with the UpdateDatabase method, because the setter is never even fired. I know it's not a NULL issue, because on the database side we're applying a default 'Unknown Engineer' at time of record creation, and that shows when I create a new record. I can also confirm it is not a DataContext issue, because every field except for these two fires as expected. Feel like I must just be missing a setting in the XAML but I'm at a loss here.

Is the setter not running at all or is the equality check ( _mfgEngineer != value ) always false?

Does Engineer implement INotifyPropertyChanged? We might need to see your .xaml

@Mark it does not run at all. I've got a breakpoint on the (_mfgEngineer != value) and it is never caught.

@KyleKW It does, do you need the entire XAML for the page? Or code for the Engineer class?

It is the UserID property of the Engineer object in CurrentEngChangeNotice.ProductEng or CurrentEngChangeNotice.MfgEng that is changing, but not the value of the ProductEng or MfgEng property.

With a read-only UserID (as it should be) you would have noticed this immediately.

@Clemens Is that because of my binding SelectedValue = "{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.MfgEng.UserID}"? If I remove .UserID, it doesn't show any value at all since pointing to a complex object and not just a string. Have I just configured the Engineer class incorrectly to work this way? New to WPF so apologies if this is normally a simple answer.

Instead of Engineer ProductEng and Engineer MfgEng, the CurrentEngChangeNotice class (or whatever the name is) should have ID ProductEngUserID and ID MfgEngUserID properties, which you bind like SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.ProductEngUserID.

@Clemens I see now. Since my value is bound to a string field of Engineer, my underlying property must also be a simple string. I was mistakenly assuming that the ItemSource objects needed to match the type of the bound (parent) object, but really the property needed to match the bound field. Thanks for the help!

That's why we have SelectedValue/SelectedValuePath, in contrast to SelectedItem, which must be bound to an object that equals an element in the ItemsSource collection.

With a Binding like
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.ProductEng.UserID}"

(which is TwoWay by default), it is the UserID property of the Engineer object held by the ProductEng property that is changing, but not the ProductEng property itself.
You should change the property declarations like shown below (assuming the UserID property type is string).
public string ProductEngID
{
    get { return _productEngineerID; }
    set 
    {
        if (_productEngineerID != value)
        {
            _productEngineerID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            UpdateDatabase("PRODUCT_ENG", _productEngineerID);
        }

    }
}

public string MfgEngID
{
    get { return _mfgEngineerID; }
    set
    {
        if (_mfgEngineerID != value)
        {
            _mfgEngineerID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            UpdateDatabase("MFG_ENG", _mfgEngineerID);
        }

    }
}

and change the SelectedValue Bindings to this:
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.ProductEngID}"
SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentEngChangeNotice.MfgEngID}"


You may also consider declaring UserID as a read-only property, in order to avoid problems like this. The original Bindings would have failed und thus given an indication of what was wrong.
